# StackOverflowError at ReentrantLock?

Tags: android, stack-overflow

What is the cause for this kind of error, `textview?` 
`What is ReentrantLock?` ***please help me.***

```
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):FATALEXCEPTION:main
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):java.lang.StackOverflowError
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atjava.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:182)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atjava.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:261)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atjava.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.remove(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:370)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(ViewTreeObserver.java:377)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4041)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1647)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1374)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1645)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1374)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1645)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1374)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1645)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1374)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1645)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1374)
12-3114:34:33.409E/AndroidRuntime(23722):atandroid.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1645)
```

Comment: Here[this][1] might help you. it occurs due to recursive calls


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765352/stackoverflow-on-android-2-3-3-devices-only

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html for reenttantLick

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the ReentrantLock is a reason of your problem. It might just be a place where the stack happened to overflow as a result of being to big already. I would suggest looking at your view structure and any invalidate() calls you make.